# Can't add new user to wso2 default user store once I mapped the SCIM claim to LDAP attributes

Tags: ldap, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I'm working on WSO2 IS [SCIM](http://www.simplecloud.info/) endpoints for user management.

Now I could add a new user to LDAP user store by mapping the SCIM claim to the existing attributes of Apache directory.

But now I can't add a new user to default user store once I mapped the SCIM claim to LDAP attributes.

Is there any option to create new users to different user stores according to our requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using two use stores, you need to map the attributes correctly using claim management.  Under "Mapped Attribute (s)" you need to follow the pattern....

> {domain_name/attribute_Name};{domain_name/attribute_Name}; {domain_name/attribute_Name};

and so on.. But for default user store, you do not want to provide the domain name.  As an example,  if you have two user stores, one is default and other one with domain "LDAP" then patter would be as follows for http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress

> email;LDAP/mail

Comment: Can i use two user store (default and LDAP) at the same time in wso2 Identity Server??

Comment: yes.. with 4.5.0 you can use it. It means you can configure multiple user stores